# Add list of item in editor view page of orchard cms driver class

Tags: orchardcms

I try to create **custom content part** with following specification.

I need to add list of items in database with same editor template view page of driver.

I want to include one form with required fields with an add button, by using this add button I want to add more number of rows with given field values in database.

I have checked **Orchard** documentation in this [link](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/), they provide sample with single item add in editor template page. In my case I need to add multiple items in editor page.

In display view page of driver, I want to retrieve collection of data from database and rendered in display view page.

Please share some details for this.

Thanks,

Comment: Please explain some more with your specific use case. What is your 'List of items'? What do you mean with 'Add more number of rows with given field values'?

Comment: Check the ContentPicker-Field, attach it to your part and see if it suits your needs. If that ain't the case please update your question like devqon already said.